# Architexa doesn't seem to want to diagram private methods

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, sequence-diagram

I installed the Architexa plugin to my Eclipse and now trying to use it to create a sequence diagram of my Java code.

When I click on the arrow of a call in the diagram which expands a list of possible calls to attach to the sequence and then click on a private method it doesn't get put into the sequence. Why? Is there a way to do it? This method is a crucial piece of seeing the big picture. I don't get why this tool would have this limitation.

I would greatly appreciate some feedback from anyone with some experience with this tool.

Thanks.